# Yii: Does renderPartial caches content of view files?

Tags: yii

I need to render and display instances of different models(comments, polls, etc) on the same page. Those instances are sorted by date, so it is possible that there will be couple comments then poll then another commetns and once more poll and so on.

So I am calling renderPartial in a loop. I am afraid that this can work slow as each renderPartial needs to read file from hdd.

So my question is: does renderPartial caches content of the file somewhere in the memory during one http request? So calling renderpartial multiple times will not touch hdd every time.

Answer (score 1):

Yii will not cache anything until you instruct it to do so. You can cache whole page, or just a page part, it's up to you really, you should follow [Yii's cache tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) to find out how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a admin or something, but I'm pretty sure that OS will cache the file, so you don't need to worry about that.

Here is 1 alternative: you can prepare a set of all the data(as array for example, or some custom type of structure/object). Then change you code in the view to check for this array and loop trough it. This way you can send the output in single `renderPartial` call.